Logic App Networking Access Restrictions set via Bicep
I am deploying a Standard Logic App using Bicep.
I am attempting to set "Enabled from select virtual networks and IP addresses" and associated "site access and rules"
The code below results in none of the three "Public network access" options being set so I'm guessing it is set to null. Has anyone achieved this?
resource logicApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' = {
  name: logicAppName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp,workflowapp'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
    
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: hostingPlan.id
    virtualNetworkSubnetId: subnetLogicAppId
    siteConfig: {
      cors: {
        allowedOrigins: [
          'https://portal.azure.com'
        ]
      }
      ftpsState: 'Disabled'
      minTlsVersion: '1.2'
      use32BitWorkerProcess: false
      netFrameworkVersion: '6.0'
      functionsRuntimeScaleMonitoringEnabled: false
      vnetRouteAllEnabled: true
      **publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
      ipSecurityRestrictions: [
        {
          ipAddress: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32'
          action: 'Allow'
          tag: 'Default'
          priority: 300
          name: 'laptop'
          description: 'laptop IP'
        }
        {
          ipAddress: 'Any'
          action: 'Deny'
          priority: 2147483647
          name: 'Deny all'
          description: 'Deny all access'
        }
      ]
      ipSecurityRestrictionsDefaultAction:'Deny'
      scmIpSecurityRestrictions: [
        {
          ipAddress: 'Any'
          action: 'Deny'
          priority: 2147483647
          name: 'Deny all'
          description: 'Deny all access'
        }
      ]
      scmIpSecurityRestrictionsDefaultAction:'Deny'
      scmIpSecurityRestrictionsUseMain: true**
    }
    
    httpsOnly: true
  }
}



Attempting to set "Enabled from select virtual networks and IP addresses" and associated "site access and rules":

To ensure that public network access is correctly configured for the Logic App, you need to explicitly set the PublicNetworkAccess property to 'Enabled'.
publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
Enabling it will select the required setting "Enabled from select virtual networks and IP addresses" under Networking section of logic apps.
Modified code:
param logicAppName string = 'mydapsialsjd'
param location string = 'West Europe'
resource storage 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2019-06-01' = {
  name: 'stlogicenvironmentlatest'
  location: location
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_GRS'
  }
  properties: {
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
  }
}
resource plan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'plan-logicnew'
  location: location
  sku: {
    tier: 'WorkflowStandard'
    name: 'WS1'
  }
  properties: {
}
}
resource logicApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' = {
  name: logicAppName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp,workflowapp'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
    
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: plan.id
    siteConfig: {
      cors: {
        allowedOrigins: [
          'https://portal.azure.com'
        ]
      }
      ftpsState: 'Disabled'
      minTlsVersion: '1.2'
      use32BitWorkerProcess: false
      netFrameworkVersion: '6.0'
      functionsRuntimeScaleMonitoringEnabled: false
      vnetRouteAllEnabled: true
      publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
      ipSecurityRestrictions: [
        {
          ipAddress: '10.0.0.0/32'
          action: 'Allow'
          tag: 'Default'
          priority: 300
          name: 'laptop'
          description: 'laptop IP'
        }
        {
          ipAddress: 'Any'
          action: 'Deny'
          priority: 2147483647
          name: 'Deny all'
          description: 'Deny all access'
        }
      ]
      ipSecurityRestrictionsDefaultAction:'Deny'
      scmIpSecurityRestrictions: [
        {
          ipAddress: 'Any'
          action: 'Deny'
          priority: 2147483647
          name: 'Deny all'
          description: 'Deny all access'
        }
      ]
      scmIpSecurityRestrictionsDefaultAction:'Deny'
      scmIpSecurityRestrictionsUseMain: true
    }
    
    httpsOnly: true
  }
}

Deployment succeeded:




I tried that but it resulted in "There was a conflict. SiteConfig.PublicNetworkAccess cannot be set by itself. Please use the Site.PublicNetworkAccess property". I'm in North Europe and using Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-09-01 but beyond that I can't see any other differences yet.

Even I received the same error when I tried before. After setting up the publicNetworkAddress property under siteconfig block, error was disappeared. @user195166

I also create a private endpoint - does this somehow change the behaviour?

No it should not. Can you clear the cache and try again the same code provided by me. @user195166

Working now I think changing the hosting plan to the 2021 version did the trick - many thanks
